# JavaScript - Regex Credit Card expiry date auto format

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a function that will get content from input element and try to format numbers entered in input box in MM/YY. Following is a solution that I've, I want to reduce numbers of lines it has. Can anybody help me write a better function to do this?

If you see this, it auto inserts slash. Working demo: https://codepen.io/ermauliks/pen/EXBryQ?editors=1010

```
function formatString(string) {
        return string.replace(
            /^([1-9]\/|[2-9])$/g, '0$1/' // To handle 3/ > 03/
        ).replace(
            /^(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1})$/g, '$1/' // 11 > 11/
        ).replace(
            /^([0-1]{1})([3-9]{1})$/g, '0$1/$2' // 13 > 01/3
        ).replace(
            /^(\d)\/(\d\d)$/g, '0$1/$2' // To handle 1/11 > 01/11
        ).replace(
            /^(0?[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1})([0-9]{2})$/g, '$1/$2' // 141 > 01/41
        ).replace(
            /^([0]{1,})\/|[0]{1,}$/g, '0' // To handle 0/ > 0 and 00 > 0
        ).replace(
            /[^\d\/]|^[\/]{0,}$/g, '' // To allow only numbers and /
        ).replace(
            /\/\//g, '/' // Prevent entering more than 1 /
        );
    }
    event.target.value = formatString(value);
```

Comment: If you have working code you could try posting here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Maulik - were you able to get a robust solution? I am looking to implement a similar one. The problems in this is, after entering a valid date, if you edit a month, the validation is not working properly

Answer (score 13):

Here is an enhancement version where user doesn't enter the / (automatically added) and allows deletion (other solutions block on deleting the slash):

```
function cc_expires_format(string) {
    return string.replace(
        /[^0-9]/g, '' // To allow only numbers
    ).replace(
        /^([2-9])$/g, '0$1' // To handle 3 > 03
    ).replace(
        /^(1{1})([3-9]{1})$/g, '0$1/$2' // 13 > 01/3
    ).replace(
        /^0{1,}/g, '0' // To handle 00 > 0
    ).replace(
        /^([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{1,2}).*/g, '$1/$2' // To handle 113 > 11/3
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    function formatString(e) {
  var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  var code = event.keyCode;
  var allowedKeys = [8];
  if (allowedKeys.indexOf(code) !== -1) {
    return;
  }

  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(
    /^([1-9]\/|[2-9])$/g, '0$1/' // 3 > 03/
  ).replace(
    /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/g, '$1/' // 11 > 11/
  ).replace(
    /^1([3-9])$/g, '01/$1' // 13 > 01/3 //UPDATED by NAVNEET
  // ).replace(
  //   /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-9]{2})$/g, '$1/$2' // 141 > 01/41
  ).replace(
    /^0\/|0+$/g, '0' // 0/ > 0 and 00 > 0 //UPDATED by NAVNEET
  ).replace(
    /[^\d|^\/]*/g, '' // To allow only digits and `/` //UPDATED by NAVNEET
  ).replace(
    /\/\//g, '/' // Prevent entering more than 1 `/`
  );
}
```

Comment: hello! what needs to be change to accept full year format mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You can't format something at the same time the user is typing, don't use onkeyup for that, imagine the nightmare for the user! (he wants to type 12/18 and when he types 1 the input content is immediately changed to 01!).

I think a better way is to use two input fields in your form and to fire your formatting function when an input field loses the focus using the onblur event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
        function formatExpMonthYear() {
            var val = this.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
            this.value = /^\d$/.test(val) ? '0' + val : val;
            // fire a validation function/display a validation icon
        }
        myform.elements.expMonth.addEventListener('blur', formatExpMonthYear);
        myform.elements.expYear.addEventListener('blur', formatExpMonthYear);
        myform.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            // fire validation functions/display validation icons
        });
    });
})(); 
</script>
...
<form id="myform">
    <input placeholder="MM" type="text" name="expMonth" pattern="\d\d?"/>
    /
    <input placeholder="YY" type="text" name="expYear" pattern="\d\d?"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but, this doesn't seem to be working as my function works. It doesn't cover few cases. For example if I press `13`, it should format date as `01/3`.

Comment: That isn't a reasonable date, perhaps you could store the str.relpace in this answer into a variable. Then, check if it matches the string that was passed in, if it matches then it wasn't a valid date entered (because the regex didn't reformat it). You may have to add other logic checks for other ways of entering invalid dates but that would be a start

Comment: @MaulikSuchak: If I understand well, you want something that updates the input field content each time you press a key, isn't?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes.

Comment: @MaulikSuchak: ok, I believed that you want something to format the string when the input looses the focus. I will edit my answer if I have an idea.

Comment: @MaulikSuchak: If I were you, I will use two fields (one for the month, one for the year) and the onblur/onsubmit event (instead of to be tyranic with onkeyup) to check if the date is correct. (Whatever you have to do this check on server side too).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - I do need a single field though. But, I'll try your solution too. Thanks.

Comment: @MaulikSuchak: don't make things complicated when you can make them more simple. When the submit event occurs, you are free to do what you want with the data.

Answer (score 0):

With future date validation:

```
export function cardExpiryValidator(string) {
    const str = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/^([2-9])$/g, '0$1').replace(/^(1{1})([3-9]{1})$/g, '0$1/$2').replace(/^0{1,}/g, '0').replace(/^([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{1,2}).*/g, '$1/$2');
    if (str.length === 5 && ccExpired(str)) {
        return str.slice(0, 4);
    }
    return str
    function ccExpired(date) {
        const dateArr = date.split("/");
        const exYear = +dateArr[1] + 2000;
        const exMonth = +dateArr[0] - 1;

        const exDay = new Date(exYear, exMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
        const dateObj = new Date(exYear, exMonth, exDay - 2);
        const dateNow = new Date();
        return dateNow > dateObj;
    }
}
```